# How do I match a regex in which the next non-space character is not a "/"?

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I express in regex the letter `"s"` whose next non-space character is not a `"/"`?

- These should match: `"s"`, `"str"`
- These should not: `"s/m"`, `"s /n"`

I tried this

```
"str" =~ /s[^[[:space:]]]^\// #=> nil
```

but it does not even match the simple use case.

Comment: Maybe [`/s(?![[:space:]]*\/)/`](http://rubular.com/r/hM1pwUCqxa)?

Comment: That looks to be the winner

Comment: Good, posted as an [answer with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47383157/3832970). Just as FYI: in Ruby 2.4, you may use `pattern.match?(string)` to check if there is a match or not. Like `/s(?![[:space:]]*\/)/.match?("str")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to match any `s` that is not followed with any 0+ whitespace chars and a `/` after them.

Use

```
/s(?![[:space:]]*\/)/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/hM1pwUCqxa).

**Details**

- `s` - the letter `s`
- `(?![[:space:]]*\/)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are

  - `[[:space:]]*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\/` - a `/`.

Comment: It depends on the interpretation of "the next non-space character" in the question. If it is meant to mean "in case any such character exists", then this answer gives the right result, but if it is to mean "it requires the existence of such character", then this is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you merely want to know the number of `'s'` characters that are not followed by zero or more spaces and then a forward slash (as opposed to their indices in the string), you don't have to use a regular expression.

```
"sea shells /by the sea s/hore".delete(" ").gsub("s/", "").count("s")
  #=> 3
```

If you only want to know if there is at least one such `'s'` you could replace `count("s")` with `include?("s")`.

I'm not arguing that this is preferable to the use of a regular expression.